# Component isn't refreshing scope on $emit

Tags: angularjs, components

I have a component in AngularJS, with a value saved to the scope which provides a URL to an `<img>` in the view. When a user changes the image, a controller emits a change via `$rootScope.$emit`, and the URL value updates, and so should the view displaying the new uploaded image:

```
angular.module('ppApp').component('mainnav', {
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/nav/nav.main-nav.tpl.htm',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){

        vm.avatarimage = '../p3sweb/avatarImage';

        $rootScope.$on('refreshAvatar', function(){
           console.log('change avatar')
           vm.avatarimage = '../p3sweb/avatarImage';
        })

    }]
})

//Controller
$rootScope.$emit('refreshAvatar',function(){ //value refreshAvatar emitted when they have loaded new image

})

//view
<img data-ng-src="{{$ctrl.avatarimage}}" alt="users profile pic" class="profile-pic-radius">
```

The emission is picked up and the 'change avatar' is logged, but the image doesn't update in less I refresh the page.

**Question**

How do I refresh just the component so it updates the scope and displays the new image that has just been uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue of Angular.js but you need a trick to update your image since `img` tag won't get updated until its source gets changed.

You can add timestamp at the end of the image source URI.

```
...
    $rootScope.$on('refreshAvatar', function(){
        console.log('change avatar')
        // SEE HERE!!!
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        vm.avatarimage = '../p3sweb/avatarImage' + '?' + timestamp;
    })
...
```

Comment: With pleasure. Glad that helped you.

Comment: Enjoy your weekend, too :)